# Can I move a soldier from one account to another in Battlefield 2142?

Tags: battlefield-2142

When Battlefield 2142 first came out, my brother created an account and then we both played created a soldier in the account. Now the price for 2142 had dropped drastically and I've bought another copy of the game so we can play online together. However, you can't use the same account to play online at the same time, so is it possible for me to "move" the soldier from his account to my account? I'd rather not loose the solider that I've been playing on for the last 4-odd years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Unfortunately, that is the simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

I personally doubt it.

The only way you're going to find out is by contacting EA Support [here](https://help.ea.com/)

After clicking that link, you will need to click the box on the right that says "Talk to a game adviser". This will prompt you to login to your account and then you will need to fill in which game you want support with and what platform it's for. They then offer an e-mail based support (from what I could see). There is also an option for calling them directly.

Having had personal experience of some EA support regarding account issues I doubt they will honour your request I'm afraid. It's definitely worth a try though.

Comment: I think sending an e-mail is probably worth my time, but as I've seen horrific support from in in the past as well I don't hold much hope.